# Cassandra: denormalization and paging

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, denormalization

I'm trying to understand and to get familiar with cassandra data models.
This article explains some basic modeling rules:

https://www.ebayinc.com/stories/blogs/tech/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

Option 3 shows an denormalized data model:

[image]

Am I getting the things right, that the "user_by_item" table has the following structure?

```
CREATE TABLE "user_by_item" (
    item_id int,
    users list<User>
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
)
```

If yes: it is clear that I can get all users by item_id with one query. But there is no possibility to page through the user list then.

Did I understand the table structure right and how are lists of items managed then, especially if they can get very large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, that article is 6 years old.  For its time, it was a great article, but Cassandra has changed *significantly* since then.  Case in point, collections didn't exist in Cassandra 1.1, which I *think* was the most-recent version at the time of this writing.

> Am I getting the things right, that the "user_by_item" table has the following structure?

Yes, I think you are understanding it.  Using item_id as a single `PRIMARY KEY` on users_by_item, while storing users as a collection is one way that you could do this.  But, it limits your query flexibility to pulling all of the users back at once.

Probably the most *query-friendly* way to build that query table, is with a clustering key on `user_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE user_by_item (
  item_id int,
  user_id int,
  email text,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((item_id),user_id)
);
```

This way, I can query for all users tied to item 111:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM user_by_item WHERE item_id=111;

 item_id | user_id | email   | name
---------+---------+---------+------
     111 |     123 | jp@ebay |  Jay
     111 |     456 | jd@ebay | John

(2 rows)
```

And I can also query just Jay, if I know his `user_id`:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM user_by_item WHERE item_id=111
                               AND user_id=123;

 item_id | user_id | email   | name
---------+---------+---------+------
     111 |     123 | jp@ebay |  Jay

(1 rows)
```

This gives me a bit more query flexibility, while also storing all of the user data by `item_id`.

**Pro tips:**

- Don't encapsulate your table name in double quotes unless you have to.  It forces Cassandra to maintain its case, but can make data retrieval a frustrating experience later on.
- When modeling for Cassandra, it is a common practice to use natural keys like `name` = "Jay."  The whole point of a surrogate key like `_id`, was that something could be referenced from a main table without risking it being misspelled every time it was needed/stored.  In Cassandra we don't have things like foreign keys, so natural keys help you cut out some unnecessary columns.
- Primary keys in Cassandra cannot change.  So the exception to the above rule, is if a primary key value is predicted to change (Jay legally changes his `name`, for instance) then using a surrogate key becomes a good idea.